# Print in JavaCC

Tags: java, javacc

I made a simple javacc parser to print text in the command prompt:

```
options
{
  static = true;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(Printer)
package test2;
import java.io.*;

public class Printer
{
  public static void main(String args []) throws ParseException
  {
    Printer parser = new Printer(System.in);
    parser.parse(System.out);
  }
}

PARSER_END(Printer)

SKIP:
{
  "\n"
| "\r"
| "\r\n"
}


TOKEN:{
  < PRINT: "print" >
| < STR: (["a"-"z"] | ["A"-"Z"])* >
}

void parse(PrintStream ps) :
{
  Token t;
}
{
  (< PRINT > " " t = < STR >
  {
    System.out.println(t.image);
  })
}
```

But the problem is that it can not print any characters other than a-z.
How do I bring it to print all unicode characters.

Comment: It is not a problem of *printing* characters outsize the `A-Z` range, it is a problem of *recognizing* them. Change your expression for `STR` to include unicode, and they should show up in the output.

Comment: Try `< STR: (["\u0000"-"\uFFFF"])+ >`, it should match *any* unicode character from the Java 2 range. If you are interested only in certain range of code points (say, only Arabic or only Korean) you should use the values for the beginning and the end of your target range instead of `\u0000` and `\uFFFF`. Note the `+` instead of a `*`: you do not want to enable empty matches on strings.

Comment: When I do that nothing happens when I press ENTER. It just makes a new line.

Comment: Try restricting your range somewhat to *not* include the `\n` and `\r`. I cannot debug this remotely, so you need to play with your code and see what happens when you change things.

Comment: I solved the problem by copying some code from a javacc example.

Comment: Great! You could paste your solution into an answer, and accept it. This would make the answer available to anyone who finds your question through a search engine.

Comment: I can not do that until about 6 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem and this is how the code looks now:

```
options
{
  UNICODE_INPUT = true;
  static = true;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(Printer)
package test2;
import java.io.*;

public class Printer
{
  public static void main(String args []) throws ParseException
  {
    Printer parser = new Printer(System.in);
    parser.parse(System.out);
  }
}

PARSER_END(Printer)

SKIP:
{
  "\n"
| "\r"
| "\r\n"
}

TOKEN:
{
  < PRINT: "print" >
| < STR: (< LETTER >)+>
| < #LETTER:
      [  // all chars for which Character.isIdentifierPart is true
         "\u0000"-"\u0008",
         "\u000e"-"\u001b",
         "$",
         "0"-"9",
         "A"-"Z",
         "_",
         "a"-"z",
         "\u007f"-"\u009f",
         "\u00a2"-"\u00a5",
         "\u00aa",
         "\u00b5",
         "\u00ba",
         "\u00c0"-"\u00d6",
         "\u00d8"-"\u00f6",
         "\u00f8"-"\u021f",
         "\u0222"-"\u0233",
         "\u0250"-"\u02ad",
         "\u02b0"-"\u02b8",
         "\u02bb"-"\u02c1",
         "\u02d0"-"\u02d1",
         "\u02e0"-"\u02e4",
         "\u02ee",
         "\u0300"-"\u034e",
         "\u0360"-"\u0362",
         "\u037a",
         "\u0386",
         "\u0388"-"\u038a",
         "\u038c",
         "\u038e"-"\u03a1",
         "\u03a3"-"\u03ce",
         "\u03d0"-"\u03d7",
         "\u03da"-"\u03f3",
         "\u0400"-"\u0481",
         "\u0483"-"\u0486",
         "\u048c"-"\u04c4",
         "\u04c7"-"\u04c8",
         "\u04cb"-"\u04cc",
         "\u04d0"-"\u04f5",
         "\u04f8"-"\u04f9",
         "\u0531"-"\u0556",
         "\u0559",
         "\u0561"-"\u0587",
         "\u0591"-"\u05a1",
         "\u05a3"-"\u05b9",
         "\u05bb"-"\u05bd",
         "\u05bf",
         "\u05c1"-"\u05c2",
         "\u05c4",
         "\u05d0"-"\u05ea",
         "\u05f0"-"\u05f2",
         "\u0621"-"\u063a",
         "\u0640"-"\u0655",
         "\u0660"-"\u0669",
         "\u0670"-"\u06d3",
         "\u06d5"-"\u06dc",
         "\u06df"-"\u06e8",
         "\u06ea"-"\u06ed",
         "\u06f0"-"\u06fc",
         "\u070f"-"\u072c",
         "\u0730"-"\u074a",
         "\u0780"-"\u07b0",
         "\u0901"-"\u0903",
         "\u0905"-"\u0939",
         "\u093c"-"\u094d",
         "\u0950"-"\u0954",
         "\u0958"-"\u0963",
         "\u0966"-"\u096f",
         "\u0981"-"\u0983",
         "\u0985"-"\u098c",
         "\u098f"-"\u0990",
         "\u0993"-"\u09a8",
         "\u09aa"-"\u09b0",
         "\u09b2",
         "\u09b6"-"\u09b9",
         "\u09bc",
         "\u09be"-"\u09c4",
         "\u09c7"-"\u09c8",
         "\u09cb"-"\u09cd",
         "\u09d7",
         "\u09dc"-"\u09dd",
         "\u09df"-"\u09e3",
         "\u09e6"-"\u09f3",
         "\u0a02",
         "\u0a05"-"\u0a0a",
         "\u0a0f"-"\u0a10",
         "\u0a13"-"\u0a28",
         "\u0a2a"-"\u0a30",
         "\u0a32"-"\u0a33",
         "\u0a35"-"\u0a36",
         "\u0a38"-"\u0a39",
         "\u0a3c",
         "\u0a3e"-"\u0a42",
         "\u0a47"-"\u0a48",
         "\u0a4b"-"\u0a4d",
         "\u0a59"-"\u0a5c",
         "\u0a5e",
         "\u0a66"-"\u0a74",
         "\u0a81"-"\u0a83",
         "\u0a85"-"\u0a8b",
         "\u0a8d",
         "\u0a8f"-"\u0a91",
         "\u0a93"-"\u0aa8",
         "\u0aaa"-"\u0ab0",
         "\u0ab2"-"\u0ab3",
         "\u0ab5"-"\u0ab9",
         "\u0abc"-"\u0ac5",
         "\u0ac7"-"\u0ac9",
         "\u0acb"-"\u0acd",
         "\u0ad0",
         "\u0ae0",
         "\u0ae6"-"\u0aef",
         "\u0b01"-"\u0b03",
         "\u0b05"-"\u0b0c",
         "\u0b0f"-"\u0b10",
         "\u0b13"-"\u0b28",
         "\u0b2a"-"\u0b30",
         "\u0b32"-"\u0b33",
         "\u0b36"-"\u0b39",
         "\u0b3c"-"\u0b43",
         "\u0b47"-"\u0b48",
         "\u0b4b"-"\u0b4d",
         "\u0b56"-"\u0b57",
         "\u0b5c"-"\u0b5d",
         "\u0b5f"-"\u0b61",
         "\u0b66"-"\u0b6f",
         "\u0b82"-"\u0b83",
         "\u0b85"-"\u0b8a",
         "\u0b8e"-"\u0b90",
         "\u0b92"-"\u0b95",
         "\u0b99"-"\u0b9a",
         "\u0b9c",
         "\u0b9e"-"\u0b9f",
         "\u0ba3"-"\u0ba4",
         "\u0ba8"-"\u0baa",
         "\u0bae"-"\u0bb5",
         "\u0bb7"-"\u0bb9",
         "\u0bbe"-"\u0bc2",
         "\u0bc6"-"\u0bc8",
         "\u0bca"-"\u0bcd",
         "\u0bd7",
         "\u0be7"-"\u0bef",
         "\u0c01"-"\u0c03",
         "\u0c05"-"\u0c0c",
         "\u0c0e"-"\u0c10",
         "\u0c12"-"\u0c28",
         "\u0c2a"-"\u0c33",
         "\u0c35"-"\u0c39",
         "\u0c3e"-"\u0c44",
         "\u0c46"-"\u0c48",
         "\u0c4a"-"\u0c4d",
         "\u0c55"-"\u0c56",
         "\u0c60"-"\u0c61",
         "\u0c66"-"\u0c6f",
         "\u0c82"-"\u0c83",
         "\u0c85"-"\u0c8c",
         "\u0c8e"-"\u0c90",
         "\u0c92"-"\u0ca8",
         "\u0caa"-"\u0cb3",
         "\u0cb5"-"\u0cb9",
         "\u0cbe"-"\u0cc4",
         "\u0cc6"-"\u0cc8",
         "\u0cca"-"\u0ccd",
         "\u0cd5"-"\u0cd6",
         "\u0cde",
         "\u0ce0"-"\u0ce1",
         "\u0ce6"-"\u0cef",
         "\u0d02"-"\u0d03",
         "\u0d05"-"\u0d0c",
         "\u0d0e"-"\u0d10",
         "\u0d12"-"\u0d28",
         "\u0d2a"-"\u0d39",
         "\u0d3e"-"\u0d43",
         "\u0d46"-"\u0d48",
         "\u0d4a"-"\u0d4d",
         "\u0d57",
         "\u0d60"-"\u0d61",
         "\u0d66"-"\u0d6f",
         "\u0d82"-"\u0d83",
         "\u0d85"-"\u0d96",
         "\u0d9a"-"\u0db1",
         "\u0db3"-"\u0dbb",
         "\u0dbd",
         "\u0dc0"-"\u0dc6",
         "\u0dca",
         "\u0dcf"-"\u0dd4",
         "\u0dd6",
         "\u0dd8"-"\u0ddf",
         "\u0df2"-"\u0df3",
         "\u0e01"-"\u0e3a",
         "\u0e3f"-"\u0e4e",
         "\u0e50"-"\u0e59",
         "\u0e81"-"\u0e82",
         "\u0e84",
         "\u0e87"-"\u0e88",
         "\u0e8a",
         "\u0e8d",
         "\u0e94"-"\u0e97",
         "\u0e99"-"\u0e9f",
         "\u0ea1"-"\u0ea3",
         "\u0ea5",
         "\u0ea7",
         "\u0eaa"-"\u0eab",
         "\u0ead"-"\u0eb9",
         "\u0ebb"-"\u0ebd",
         "\u0ec0"-"\u0ec4",
         "\u0ec6",
         "\u0ec8"-"\u0ecd",
         "\u0ed0"-"\u0ed9",
         "\u0edc"-"\u0edd",
         "\u0f00",
         "\u0f18"-"\u0f19",
         "\u0f20"-"\u0f29",
         "\u0f35",
         "\u0f37",
         "\u0f39",
         "\u0f3e"-"\u0f47",
         "\u0f49"-"\u0f6a",
         "\u0f71"-"\u0f84",
         "\u0f86"-"\u0f8b",
         "\u0f90"-"\u0f97",
         "\u0f99"-"\u0fbc",
         "\u0fc6",
         "\u1000"-"\u1021",
         "\u1023"-"\u1027",
         "\u1029"-"\u102a",
         "\u102c"-"\u1032",
         "\u1036"-"\u1039",
         "\u1040"-"\u1049",
         "\u1050"-"\u1059",
         "\u10a0"-"\u10c5",
         "\u10d0"-"\u10f6",
         "\u1100"-"\u1159",
         "\u115f"-"\u11a2",
         "\u11a8"-"\u11f9",
         "\u1200"-"\u1206",
         "\u1208"-"\u1246",
         "\u1248",
         "\u124a"-"\u124d",
         "\u1250"-"\u1256",
         "\u1258",
         "\u125a"-"\u125d",
         "\u1260"-"\u1286",
         "\u1288",
         "\u128a"-"\u128d",
         "\u1290"-"\u12ae",
         "\u12b0",
         "\u12b2"-"\u12b5",
         "\u12b8"-"\u12be",
         "\u12c0",
         "\u12c2"-"\u12c5",
         "\u12c8"-"\u12ce",
         "\u12d0"-"\u12d6",
         "\u12d8"-"\u12ee",
         "\u12f0"-"\u130e",
         "\u1310",
         "\u1312"-"\u1315",
         "\u1318"-"\u131e",
         "\u1320"-"\u1346",
         "\u1348"-"\u135a",
         "\u1369"-"\u1371",
         "\u13a0"-"\u13f4",
         "\u1401"-"\u166c",
         "\u166f"-"\u1676",
         "\u1681"-"\u169a",
         "\u16a0"-"\u16ea",
         "\u1780"-"\u17d3",
         "\u17db",
         "\u17e0"-"\u17e9",
         "\u180b"-"\u180e",
         "\u1810"-"\u1819",
         "\u1820"-"\u1877",
         "\u1880"-"\u18a9",
         "\u1e00"-"\u1e9b",
         "\u1ea0"-"\u1ef9",
         "\u1f00"-"\u1f15",
         "\u1f18"-"\u1f1d",
         "\u1f20"-"\u1f45",
         "\u1f48"-"\u1f4d",
         "\u1f50"-"\u1f57",
         "\u1f59",
         "\u1f5b",
         "\u1f5d",
         "\u1f5f"-"\u1f7d",
         "\u1f80"-"\u1fb4",
         "\u1fb6"-"\u1fbc",
         "\u1fbe",
         "\u1fc2"-"\u1fc4",
         "\u1fc6"-"\u1fcc",
         "\u1fd0"-"\u1fd3",
         "\u1fd6"-"\u1fdb",
         "\u1fe0"-"\u1fec",
         "\u1ff2"-"\u1ff4",
         "\u1ff6"-"\u1ffc",
         "\u200c"-"\u200f",
         "\u202a"-"\u202e",
         "\u203f"-"\u2040",
         "\u206a"-"\u206f",
         "\u207f",
         "\u20a0"-"\u20af",
         "\u20d0"-"\u20dc",
         "\u20e1",
         "\u2102",
         "\u2107",
         "\u210a"-"\u2113",
         "\u2115",
         "\u2119"-"\u211d",
         "\u2124",
         "\u2126",
         "\u2128",
         "\u212a"-"\u212d",
         "\u212f"-"\u2131",
         "\u2133"-"\u2139",
         "\u2160"-"\u2183",
         "\u3005"-"\u3007",
         "\u3021"-"\u302f",
         "\u3031"-"\u3035",
         "\u3038"-"\u303a",
         "\u3041"-"\u3094",
         "\u3099"-"\u309a",
         "\u309d"-"\u309e",
         "\u30a1"-"\u30fe",
         "\u3105"-"\u312c",
         "\u3131"-"\u318e",
         "\u31a0"-"\u31b7",
         "\u3400"-"\u4db5",
         "\u4e00"-"\u9fa5",
         "\ua000"-"\ua48c",
         "\uac00"-"\ud7a3",
         "\uf900"-"\ufa2d",
         "\ufb00"-"\ufb06",
         "\ufb13"-"\ufb17",
         "\ufb1d"-"\ufb28",
         "\ufb2a"-"\ufb36",
         "\ufb38"-"\ufb3c",
         "\ufb3e",
         "\ufb40"-"\ufb41",
         "\ufb43"-"\ufb44",
         "\ufb46"-"\ufbb1",
         "\ufbd3"-"\ufd3d",
         "\ufd50"-"\ufd8f",
         "\ufd92"-"\ufdc7",
         "\ufdf0"-"\ufdfb",
         "\ufe20"-"\ufe23",
         "\ufe33"-"\ufe34",
         "\ufe4d"-"\ufe4f",
         "\ufe69",
         "\ufe70"-"\ufe72",
         "\ufe74",
         "\ufe76"-"\ufefc",
         "\ufeff",
         "\uff04",
         "\uff10"-"\uff19",
         "\uff21"-"\uff3a",
         "\uff3f",
         "\uff41"-"\uff5a",
         "\uff65"-"\uffbe",
         "\uffc2"-"\uffc7",
         "\uffca"-"\uffcf",
         "\uffd2"-"\uffd7",
         "\uffda"-"\uffdc",
         "\uffe0"-"\uffe1",
         "\uffe5"-"\uffe6",
         "\ufff9"-"\ufffb"
      ]
  >
}

TOKEN:
{
  < EQUAL: "=" >  
}

void parse(PrintStream ps) :
{
  Token t;
}
{
  (
    < PRINT > " " t = < STR >
  {
    System.out.println(t.image);
  }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify UNICODE_INPUT = true; option in your parser. Also regarding STR token you need to modify your regular expression to detect any text you want.

Hope this helps :)